# how can we develop a flutter app if android studio is working very slow? what are the reasons that it is working slow, how can we resolve this issue?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Android is working very slow more than it usual is. How can we resolve this issue so that we can get output?

I want to know the reasons that leads to extremely slow working of android studio. What are the things that a person should keep in mind while starting learning flutter app development?

I was expecting to get a output in sometime but its not at all showing output, taking a lot of time.

Comment: Use VS Code instead of Android Studio to develop Flutter Apps

Answer (score 0):

Android studio takes minimum 4 gb ram to run smoothly.

Try vs code for better performance.

In other hand you can use https://flutlab.io to develop flutter apps